# Open Problems about holomorphic dynamics in one and several dimensions.

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, holomorphic-functions

I am interested in open problems about holomorphic dynamics in one and several dimensions. Any recent reference would be greatly appreciable!!

Comment: I suggest looking at http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/open-problems-dynamical-systems. Old but open problems tend to get better with age...

Comment: Thank you very much @JohnB